# In CLR, C++ code do I need to allocat memory before calling Marshal::StructureToPtr

Tags: c++, clr, managed-c++

I have the following code to convert managed to unmanaged, and vice versa,

```
template<typename M, typename N>
class MNConv
{
public:
    /// Native to Managed
    static M N2M(N* pNative){
        return safe_cast<M>(Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(pNative), M::typeid));
    };
    // Managed to Native
    static void M2N(M managed, N* pNative){
        Marshal::StructureToPtr(managed, IntPtr(pNative), true);
    };
};
```

Do I need to call `AllocHGlobal`? If I do, how should I call it?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, you should allocate unmanaged memory block BEFORE calling to `StructureToPtr`. I understand you should perform a `Marshal::AllocHGlobal` in a higher scope to the native pointer, where you would also perform upon later a `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`.
Read carefully the [ptr parameter description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2zhzfk83(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using `AllocHGlobal` is also straightforward - pass an `Int32` or `IntPtr` object that contains the number of bytes to allocate.

Also note that you should receive and return a `M^` (handler/managed-reference to `M`) in `M2N` and `N2M` respectively.